# How to remove class at serial cells in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Some event were registered in calendar like html tables.

I would like to unregister these event by clicking them.

To realize this,I would like to removeclass continuous cells. like

When we click`3`or`4`,then `3`,`4` cell's class will be removed.

When we click `13`or`14`or`15`,then `13`,`14`,`15` cell's class will be removed.

When we click `9`, then only `9` cell's class will be removed.

Is it possible?

and are there any way to realize it?

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass();
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.aqua{
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class='aqua'>3</td>
    <td class='aqua'>4</td>
    <td>5</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td class='aqua'>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td class='aqua'>13</td>
    <td class='aqua'>14</td>
    <td class='aqua'>15</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [**`.closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target the parent *tr* element then use [**`.find()`**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target all the element with the *class* `aqua` to remove them:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.aqua').removeClass('aqua');
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.aqua{
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class='aqua'>3</td>
    <td class='aqua'>4</td>
    <td>5</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td class='aqua'>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td class='aqua'>13</td>
    <td class='aqua'>14</td>
    <td class='aqua'>15</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target only the cells having that `aqua` class to achieve this, instead of targeting every cell. Then using `.closest('tr')` find the closest parent `tr` for the clicked cell and after that using `.find('td.aqua')` find all the cells having the class `aqua` and then finally remove the class from each of them.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td.aqua").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.aqua').removeClass('aqua');
  });
});
```

```css
td{transition-duration:.5s;border:solid #000 1px;padding:10px;text-align:center}
table{border-collapse:collapse}
.aqua{background-color:#0ff}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class='aqua'>3</td>
    <td class='aqua'>4</td>
    <td>5</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td class='aqua'>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td class='aqua'>13</td>
    <td class='aqua'>14</td>
    <td class='aqua'>15</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove aqua class when clicking each row then use this

`$(function() {
  $("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).children().removeClass('aqua');
  });
});`

**OR** when clicking on the cells themselves use this

`$(function() {
      $("tr>.aqua").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('aqua');
      });
    });`

```js
$(function() {
  $("tr>.aqua").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('aqua');
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class='aqua'>3</td>
    <td class='aqua'>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td class='aqua'>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td class='aqua'>13</td>
    <td class='aqua'>14</td>
    <td class='aqua'>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just change your script like below. Your code will work perfectly according to your requirement.

```
$(function() {
  $("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).children().removeClass();
  });
});
```

or else you can change like below as well. It also work perfectly.

```
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.aqua').removeClass('aqua');
  });
});
```

Best Answer is using second method.